# Jinja templating in Airflow along with formatted text

Tags: python, format, jinja2, airflow

I'm trying to run a SQL statement to be rendered by Airflow, but I'm also trying to include a variable inside the statement which is passed in from Python. The SQL statement is just a where clause, and after the `WHERE`, I'm trying to add a datetime, minus a few seconds:

```
f" ' {{ ts - macros.timedelta(seconds={lower_delay} + 1) }} ' "
```

so I want what's in the double curly braces to be computed and rendered in Airflow, but I want to pass in this variable called `lower_delay` before it does that. I've tried varying combinations with zero, one, or two additional curly braces around `lower_delay` as well as the entire string, but I seem to get a different error each time.

What is the proper way to pass in this `lower_delay` variable (it's just a number) so that it ends up rendering correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jinja templating requires two curly braces, when you use f-strings or [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) it will replace two braces with one while rendering:

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
> {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
> text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include
> a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling:
> {{ and }}.

So the following should work:

```
f" ' {{{{ ts - macros.timedelta(seconds={lower_delay} + 1) }}}} ' "
```

Comment: I guess I never tried this combination. It worked, thank you very much.